How was it allowed and who brought the Sefer Torah out of the Kodesh Hakodoshim
Per the gemara in Bava Batra 14a-b
The Sefer Torah written by Moshe was stored in the Kodesh Hakodoshim.
Rashi in Bava Batra 14b

ספר עזרה - ספר שכתב משה ובו קורין בעזרה פרשת המלך בהקהל וכהן גדול ביה"כ:

Losely translated- The Sefer Torah that moshe wrote, from which, in the Azarah,  the king read "Hakhel" and the Kohen Gadol on Yom Kippur read

Who was the one who entered the kodesh Hakodoshim to bring out the sefer torah?
How did they deal with (ויקרא טז,ב) ואל יבוא בכל עת אל הקודש, which prohibits the entering of the Kodesh Hakodoshim other than for the Kohen Gadol on Yom Kippur (see sefer hachinuch here)

